# VirtualBox command line error

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I can run VirtualBox just fine, but when I run anything from the command line I get:

```
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the VirtualBox object!
VBoxManage.exe: error: Code CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE (0x80080005) - Server execution failed (extended info not available)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Most likely, the VirtualBox COM server is not running or failed to start.
```

This is pretty new. It used to work. I honestly can't remember what changed between the time that it worked and now. This particular error happened when I tried to run one a machine headless:

```
vboxmanage startvm VIRTUALMACHINE --type headless
```

but it happens with any command line operation.

Comment: semi duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/216692/how-to-run-a-virtualbox-vm-from-command-line

Comment: The 2 questions have nothing to do with one another. That one is asking how to do it, this one is asking about an error I get when I do it.

Comment: related question then.

Answer (score 8):

I discovered the solution [here](http://www.thesysadminhimself.com/2014/03/vboxmanage-modifyhd-coeserverexecfailure-0x80080005-server-execution-failed.html).

You must **NOT** run the cmd window as an Administrator to make VBoxManage.exe function without this error.

Comment: This didn't work for me and failed with `VBoxManage.exe: error: Cannot open the raw disk '\\.\PhysicalDrive2': VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` as I was trying to creating a linked USB drive: http://www.howtogeek.com/187721/how-to-boot-from-a-usb-drive-in-virtualbox/.  @Jens answer worked though.

Comment: That worked for me too with vagrant - do NOT run `vagrant up` as admin.

Answer (score 4):

I got it working after first starting VBox as Admin and then using a prompt with elevated privileges to create the vmdk.

Comment: I also had to uninstall virtualbox and reinstall it, running the installer as admin.  I had installed virtualbox with chocolatey before (when it did not work).

Comment: Thanks! In Windows 7 starting VirtualBox as Administrator then using an Administrator command prompt fixed the error I was getting creating a linked USB drive: http://www.howtogeek.com/187721/how-to-boot-from-a-usb-drive-in-virtualbox/.